# Why does my card deck-generating code return an empty array?

Tags: javascript

Here's the code. When I run it, the `length` of `newDeck` is 0, so it's clear that no `Cards` are being added to it...

```
function Card(number, suit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.suit = suit;
}

var deck = [];

function Deck() {
    for (i=2; i>13; i++) {
        for (j=1; j>4; j++) {
            var newCard = new Card(i,j);
            deck.push(newCard);
        }
    }
    return deck
}

var newDeck = new Deck();
console.log(newDeck.length);
```

Comment: Why is Deck a constructor function?

Comment: What kind of output do you expect the program to produce?

Comment: @Quentin Would you change it to createDeck()?

Comment: @Zetland — Yes … and since it modifies an existing array, I wouldn't give it a return statement either.

Answer (score 7):

Your loops are wrong, you want to check if the number is less than and not greater than:

```
function Deck() {
    for (i=2; i<13; i++) { //Change ">" with "<"
        for (j=1; j<4; j++) { //Change ">" with "<"
            var newCard = new Card(i,j);
            deck.push(newCard);
        }
    }
    return deck
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your indices in your for loops make it so the loop will never execute.

They are currently "i>13" and "j>4", but should be "i<=13" and "j<=4" (unless you only want 2-Q and 3 suits)